# Add tooltip tail to a CSS dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I would like my dropdown menu to have a tooltip tail under each dropdown. The CSS dropdown tutorial was easy, but I can't figure out how to add the arrow. [See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FXQuincy/xFUun/)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>

nav {
margin: 100px auto; 
text-align: center;
}

nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}


nav ul {
background: #efefef; 
background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
padding: 0 20px;
border-radius: 10px;  
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
    nav ul li:hover {
        background: #4b545f;
        background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
    }
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;
        }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
        color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
    }


nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a; position: relative;
    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 15px 40px;
            color: #fff;
        }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #4b545f;
            }

nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}

</style>
```

Comment: There are different ways: image sprite, CSS triangles (http://davidwalsh.name/css-triangles , http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/), ...

Comment: This can help too: http://cssarrowplease.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's usually accomplished by using something like the pseudo-selector `:before`, doing something like:

```
nav ul ul:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9px;
    left:20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 9px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 9px solid #EEE;
    border-left: 9px solid transparent;
    content: '';
}
```

However keep in mind your hover and submenu color is the same, so you may want to style it a bit to suit your tastes...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/vXdqu/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS pseudo-selector `:before` and borders:
http://jsfiddle.net/xFUun/2/